# What does it mean that a finite set in a vector space has this property?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

My homework problem says to let $S$ be a finite set in a vector space $V$ with the property that every $\vec x$ in $V$ has a unique representation as a linear combination of elements of $S$. Show that $S$ is a basis of $V$.

What does it mean that every $\vec x$ has a unique representation? I'm not sure how to go about interpreting this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that if $S=\{\vec s_1, \vec s_2, \ldots, \vec s_n\}$, then for every $\vec x$ there exists a unique $n$-tuple of scalars $(\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \ldots, \lambda_n)$ such that
$$
    \vec x = \lambda_1 \vec s_1 + \lambda_2 \vec s_2 + \ldots + \lambda_n \vec s_n.
$$

Answer (score 2):

You need to give little attentions on some of the definitions and examples to clear your doubts. Here is the short descriptions.

Definition 1(Spanning set): Let $V \subset \mathbb{R^n} $ be a vector space . We say
a list of vectors $v_1.... v_k \in V $ is a spanning set for V if $span (v_1.....v_k) = V $. Note that , $v_1.... v_k$ spans V if every vector $v \in V$ can be written as a linear combination of the vectors in V .

Definition 2(Linear independence): Let $V \subset \mathbb{R^n} $  be a vector space. We say a list
of vectors $v_1.... v_k \in V $ is linear independent if the vectors are not linear dependent. Another way to say this is that $v_1.... v_k \in V $ are linearly independent if their linear combinations $\lambda_1v_1+ .... +\lambda_1v_k = 0$
implies that the coefficient $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2....    \lambda_k = 0$.

Definition 3 (Basis): Let $V \subset \mathbb{R^n} $ be a vector space. We say a list of vectors $v_1.... v_k$
is a basis for $V$ (the plural is bases) if:

(1) $v_1.... v_k$is a spanning set for V , and,

(2) $v_1.... v_k$ are linearly independent.

Simplest example of the basis of $\mathbb{R^2}$ is vector $\{(1,0), (0, 1)\}$. These two vectors are linearly independent and any element of $\mathbb{R^2}$ say (a,b) can be written as linear combinations of  these two vectors. More specifically $(a, b) = a (1,0) + b (0,1)$. But any two linearly independent vectors, like (1,1) and (−1,2), will also form a basis of $\mathbb{R^2}$.

Coming to your question

One way to think of a basis is that every vector $v\in V $may be
uniquely expressed as

$v = \lambda_1v_1+ .... +\lambda_1v_k $

The existence of such a decomposition is given by the fact the vectors
$v_1.... v_k$ span V

If there were two ways to write v as a sum,

$ \lambda_1v_1+ .... +\lambda_1v_k  = \alpha_1v_1+ .... +\alpha_1v_k $

then we would have a way to write 0 as a linear combination of $v_1.... v_k$

that is we can write

$(\lambda_1 - \alpha_1)+.....(\lambda_k - \alpha_k)  = 0$

By independence we get
$\lambda_1 - \alpha_1 = .....\lambda_k - \alpha_k = 0 $ but then $\lambda_k = \alpha_k$..hence  the decomposition is unique.